# Qt - Keyboard layout

Tags: qt, layout, keyboard

are there any ways to get current keyboard layout in Qt?
Platform: Linux.
Programming language: C++.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
QLocale QApplication::keyboardInputLocale ()
```

Comment: QApplication::keyboardInputLocale().name() always returns QLocale::C. why?

Answer (score 3):

[`QLocale QInputMethod::locale()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html#locale-prop) should be used, which replaces the function `QApplication::keyboardInputLocale()` suggested in the accepted answer ([deprecated](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.13/qapplication-obsolete.html#keyboardInputLocale) in 5.13, [removed](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.14/qapplication-obsolete.html) in 5.14)

Answer (score 0):

`QLocale` C means the default and if you have an error in the code, I think the `QLocale` header is not included. I had this previously.